# why does foreach go to the last element php

Tags: php, foreach

I have $_POST array

```
    Array
(
    [dddd] => Array
        (
            [students] => Array
                (
                    [парарпа] => Array
                        (
                            [zach1] => 1
                            [zach2] => 1
                            [zach3] => 2
                            [zach4] => 3                               
                            [ekz1] => 5
                            [ekz2] => 5
                            [ekz3] => 5
                            [ekz4] =>
                        )

                    [ававп] => Array
                        (
                            [zach1] => 3
                            [zach2] => 5
                            [zach3] => 4
                            [zach4] => 2
                            [ekz1] => 4
                            [ekz2] => 3
                            [ekz3] => 2
                            [ekz4] => 
                        )

                )

            [zach1] => рпа
            [zach2] => рпарпарпар
            [zach3] => 
            [zach4] => пар
            [ekz1] => пав
            [ekz2] => авпав
            [ekz3] => ва
            [ekz4] => 
        )

    [ggg] => Array
        (
            [students] => Array
                (
                    [авпва] => Array
                        (
                            [zach1] => 3
                            [zach2] => 3
                            [zach3] => 2
                            [zach4] => 
                            [ekz1] => 4
                            [ekz2] => 
                            [ekz3] => 
                            [ekz4] => 
                        )

                )

            [zach1] => паыв
            [zach2] => авы
            [zach3] => ыва
            [zach4] => 
            [ekz1] => выа
            [ekz2] => 
            [ekz3] => 
            [ekz4] => 
        )

    [fffff] => Array
        (
            [students] => Array
                (
                    [авыв] => Array
                        (
                            [zach1] => 5
                            [zach2] => 5
                            [zach3] => 
                            [zach4] => 
                            [ekz1] => 4
                            [ekz2] => 4
                            [ekz3] => 
                            [ekz4] => 
                        )

                    [ваыыва] => Array
                        (
                            [zach1] => 3
                            [zach2] => 3
                            [zach3] => 
                            [zach4] => 
                            [ekz1] => 2
                            [ekz2] => 3
                            [ekz3] => 
                            [ekz4] => 
                        )

                )

            [zach1] => ва
            [zach2] => ва
            [zach3] => 
            [zach4] => 
            [ekz1] => ва
            [ekz2] => ва
            [ekz3] => 
            [ekz4] => 
        )

)
```

And I'm trying to

```
foreach($_POST as $groupName=>$data) {echo $groupName;}
```

and it only echoes the last one "fffff". I have no idea what the hell is going on. Help me please. echo count($_POST); echoes 3

Comment: You only have 3 items in your $_POST. Its three arrays with sub arrays.

Comment: That should not be the case. Please provide a *complete, self-contained, executable* piece of code that demonstrates exactly this problem.

Comment: Are you iterating through the array using foreach twice or more? using `foreach` moves the pointer to the array element everytime. So, if you use `foreach`, use `reset($array)` before you you iterate through the array again.

Comment: @Latheesan *"When foreach first starts executing, the internal array pointer is automatically reset to the first element of the array. This means that you do not need to call `reset()` before a foreach loop."* http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: @subZero What's your point? He's only echoing the keys of the top-level array.

Comment: It doesn't do what you claim: [counter-example](http://3v4l.org/vbFMJ)

Comment: I recieve this POST throught ajax, maybe it is the reason?

Comment: The array I provided in question is file_put_contents('1.txt', print_r($_POST, true));

Comment: what?! how? we should see more codes

Comment: I'd try to do `echo $groupName.'sometext';` to ensure your echo is working just one time.  `

Comment: You want my js code or what?
if(empty($_POST))
 die('no data');
echo count($_POST); // echoes 3
$currentWorksheetIndex = 0;
file_put_contents('1.txt', print_r($_POST, true)); // array that i provided in question
foreach($_POST as $groupName=>$data);
{
echo $groupName; die();} and it still echoes the last one key even with die() or with .'text'

Comment: And what happens if you echo the values? Are they displayed?

Comment: as i said only the last one "ffff" is displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with

```
$keys = array_keys($_POST);

for($i = 0; $i < count($keys); $i++)
{
    $data = $_POST[$keys[$i]];
    $groupName = $keys[$i];
}
```

Still got no idea why foreach working like that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

// Dummy Post Data
$_POST = array(
    'dddd' => array(
        'students' => array(
            'парарпа' => array('zach1' => 1, 'zach2' => 2, 'zach3' => 2),
            'ававп' => array('zach1' => 3, 'zach2' => 5, 'zach3' => 4),
        ),
        'zach1' => 'рпа',
        'zach2' => 'рпарпарпар'
    ),
    'ggg' => array(
        'students' => array(
            'парарпа' => array('zach1' => 1, 'zach2' => 2, 'zach3' => 2),
            'ававп' => array('zach1' => 3, 'zach2' => 5, 'zach3' => 4),
        ),
        'zach1' => 'рпа',
        'zach2' => 'рпарпарпар'
    ),
    'fffff' => array(
        'students' => array(
            'парарпа' => array('zach1' => 1, 'zach2' => 2, 'zach3' => 2),
            'ававп' => array('zach1' => 3, 'zach2' => 5, 'zach3' => 4),
        ),
        'zach1' => 'рпа',
        'zach2' => 'рпарпарпар'
    ),
);

// Test Iteration
foreach ($_POST as $key => $data)
{
    echo "<b>$key</b><br />";
    foreach ($data as $innerKey => $innerData)
    {
        if (is_array($innerData))
        {
            echo "<i>$innerKey</i><br />";
            foreach ($innerData as $studentName => $studentData)
            {
                echo "Student [$studentName] = ";
                foreach ($studentData as $studentDataKey => $studentDataValue) {
                    echo "$studentDataKey => $studentDataValue | ";
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "<i>$innerKey</i> = $innerData<br />";
        }
    }
    echo "<hr />";
}

?>
```

Output:

[image]

I can iterate through it just fine.